# How to edit exif in android Q

Tags: android-10.0, android-exifinterface

I want to create an jpg and edit its exif.
Before, I use ExifInterface:

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath)
exifInterface.setAttribute(...)
exifInterface.setAttribute(...)
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

But in Android Q, I just got a image uri from MediaStore API instead of a file path.I try to use this:

```
new ExifInterface(inputStream)
```

But when I call `saveAttributes()` ,it shows like this

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to copy original file to temp file
```

So,is there another way to deal with this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by updating ExifInterface to 1.3.1 in build.gradle (app):

```
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.1'
```

Seems to be related with this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a1ff438533881718f957ac0febd60134eb8f38f8) to `saveAttributes`, as indicated in the release notes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface#1.3.1

```
Fix saveAttributes implementation to keep the image data in MediaProvider
```