# Exifinterface saveAttributes() fail because of 'Failed to copy original file to temp file'

Tags: android, android-exifinterface

So now I'm writing custom camera, and I want to write location into images that I captured, for some reason I cannot use builder.set() here.
The file was created like this:

```
String name = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Camera"), name);
```

To make question simple, I just simply create an ExifInterface with a correct file path, and call saveAttributes() method,it looks like this:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.getAbsolutePath());
exif.saveAttributes();
```

but then I get this log,

```
D/qdgralloc: GetYUVPlaneInfo: Invalid format passed: 0x21
D/MediaScannerConnection: Scanned /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1619507958498.jpg to content://media/external_primary/images/media/11032
V/haha: Failed to copy original file to temp file
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Failed to copy original file to temp file
        at android.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:2098)
        at com.example.secondpractice.fragment.CameraFragment.takeDelayedPicture(CameraFragment.java:1042)
        at com.example.secondpractice.fragment.CameraFragment.onClick(CameraFragment.java:1301)
        at com.example.secondpractice.fragment.-$$Lambda$zncvcj43pAXOQyaoJTDWHHAg_tA.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7496)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7473)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:831)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28647)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7876)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't rename to /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1619507958498.jpg.tmp
        at android.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:2084)
        ... 14 more
```

I think problem happens here:Caused by: java.io.IOException:
Couldn't rename to /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1619507958498.jpg.tmp

By the way, the getAttributes() works fine, only saveAttributes() has the problem

please help me to check how to solve this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please show full code. Start with showing how you obtained that path.

Comment: Hi, I've just edited the problem description, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Are you using an Android 11 device? Could you save the .jpg file first? So it is a valid jpg file?

Comment: Yes, it's Android 11, and I call saveAttributes() after I correctly save this jpg file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an Android 11 device the OS is very picky concerning extensions.

You can create .jpg, .png and .webp files in DCIM directory and maybe other image files.

But not .tmp files as they are no image files.

So you are victim of the ExifInterface programmers.

If they had decided for .jpg.jpg and not for .jpg.tmp you would not have this trouble.

File an issue/report.

Comment: So if the file is not under DCIM directory, the problem can be sovled?

Comment: Yes. You can do it in the Documents directory i think. And of course in getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: Good suggestion, I will have a try, thanks a lot.